# My Windows 10 x64 PC does not recognize ANY mouse

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, mouse

I have a computer with Windows 10 Professional 64-bit. 
Specifications:

- CPU: AMD A6 6400K 3.90GHz
- Motherboard: GIGABYTE GA-F2A68HM-S1
- RAM: GEIL GV34GB1600C8DC DDR3 4GB (2X2GB) PC3-12800 1600MHz
- PSU: COOLERMASTER MASTERWATT 750W
- Antivirus/Firewall: ESET Internet Security

For some unknown reason **my computer does not recognize any mouse I connect** to it. I tried an old wired USB Logitech mouse, a [Microsoft Wireless Mobile Mouse 1850](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/mice/wireless-mobile-mouse-1850/u7z-00001) and a [Wireless Desktop 850](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/wireless-desktop-850/py9-00001) set with a keyboard (**keyboard was working fine but mouse was not**). I tested all mouse devices on another computer and they all work fine.

I tried on a USB 3.0 port, on an other USB 2.0 port (front and back side), restarted, shut down (removed power supply), and reset BIOS to default –
without results.

Legacy USB was enabled by default on BIOS. I disabled it but nothing happened.

- My USB Camera works fine.
- My USB Printer works fine.
- My USB Speakers work fine.
- My USB Stick works fine.

All my USB devices work except my mouse, so I don't think it's a USB driver issue.

One other strange thing is that BIOS GUI recognizes my mouse but, when I boot with Windows, Device Manager shows no mouse connected, no "unknown device" and the Hardware tab on Mouse Properties is empty (shown below). Same thing happens in Safe Mode.
[image: Mouse Properties - Hardware tab]

I really don't want to format my PC
just because it doesn't recognize my mouse.

Comment: Seems like I saw a computer once where there was a setting in the bios about running the mouse in some sort of legacy mode that windows 10 didn't like. You might look for such a bios setting and just try changing it.

Comment: Maybe try reinstalling your usb drivers?

Comment: @ashbygeek I disabled legacy mode but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @DrZoo all my USB devices work fine (camera, printer, stick etc). Only mouse devices are unrecognizable. I don't think there is a problem with my USB drivers.

Comment: There are a couple general troubleshooting things you could try before completely re-installing windows: `sfc /scannow` go to device manager and uninstall the driver for the mouse so that it will completely re-install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found the solution!
 I downloaded and installed [Mouse and Keyboard Center 3.2](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/downloads/mouse-keyboard-center) and after a reboot mouse came back!